# Dragging html elements and creating a new copy

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some html elements like tables and those elements are draggable to anywhere on screen. I am dragging those elements and designing my page view,however I want to. After completion of final design, I will be clicking a button that will create a new copy of that design either in html or in php file extension such that all css and styles match with my final design.

I mean to say, creating a clone of my final design in a new filename.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405076/how-to-save-a-user-made-html-page

Comment: I can't able to post image. but you can understand like i have created 5 tables using <table></table> elements and those tables are draggable to anywhere on screen to give a look however you want to and a button on the same page to generate new copy of final design of those tables. new copy either be in html or php format.

Comment: You can try the jQueryUI's Draggable component and add a function on the stop option, just add the code to add HTML in the fuction that is attache to stop

Comment: check this link http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop

Comment: my question is how would i create a new file ie. clone of my designed components. since on dragging css is getting changed everytime so how would i take care of this.?