# How to locate a parent element which contains another element

Tags: java, automated-tests, selenium-rc

For example:

I have the following structure:

```
<td>  
  <a>  
  <input id="MyID1">  
</td>

<td>  
  <a>  
  <input id="MyID2">  
</td>  

<td>  
</td>
```

We suggest that `<a>` does not have any specific attributes to locate it by them.

So 2 questions:

1. I need to locate `<a>` in second td. I know that `<a>` Im looking for is placed to the same td with "MyID2" input. How can I do that?
2. I need to locate 3rd td (empty). I know that td Im looking for is the following td for td what contain "MyID2" input. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use XPath somewhere, the following expression will find the `<a>` element in the second `<td>`:

`//td/a[../input/@id='MyID2']`

It will find all `<a>` elements, which are direct children of a `<td>` element having an `<input>` element on the same level with an id attribute equal to 'MyID2'.

Comment: It's been a while, but I don't believe XPath works on non-well-formed structured text. Here's a reference to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354322/finding-a-node-or-close-to-it-using-xpath-in-non-well-formed-html

Comment: All browsers transform non-well-formed HTML code into a "browseable", well-formed DOM model. E.g. JavaScript XPath libraries use this model to allow XPath queries for searching and accessing HTML elements. I am not too familiar with Selenium, but I would assume that Selenium works in a similar fashion. Hence my "if you can use XPath" introduction.