# Chrome xPath not working in Google Sheets IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

the first post, so hope I'm not violating anything.

Trying to get the title into Google Sheets from a specific webpage: [link](https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B079MCXWHB/?seller=A33P9XKXZF6BQO)

I have extracted the xPath from Chrome's developer tools and tried using the following 
  `IMPORTXML: =ImportXML("https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B079MCXWHB/?seller=A33P9XKXZF6BQO","//*[@id='olpProductDetails']/h1")`

I've tried to go through several forums, and tried different variations of the URL but keep getting an #N/A value with the error: Imported XML content cannot be parsed.

At this point, I'm not sure what else to really explore. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `IMPORTXML` imports only XML. `https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B079MCXWHB/?seller=A33P9XKXZF6BQO` is not XML. Try [`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en).

Comment: `IMPORTXML` is the correct function. However, it fails to parse the source of the requested page: `=IMPORTXML("https://www.amazon.in/gp/offer-listing/B079MCXWHB/?seller=A33P9XKXZF6BQO";"//div[@id='olpProductDetails']/h1")`

Answer (score 1):

IMPORTXML only is able to read the source code not the DOM shown by Chrome and only is able to get the nodes that their xPath is well-formed.

References

- [Finding a node (or close to it) using XPath in non well-formed HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/354322/1595451)
- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, informations are stored in a json inside the code source called `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('__________');` you should pick the json and decode it to get the informations inside your spreadsheet. It depends on what you are looking for.